# Preprocessor Directive Syntax and Etiquette

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

I have two unrelated questions:

1. Is it possible to use `#define` to define something other than a number? (Such as an extended ASCII character).
2. Is it considered good practice to use preprocessor directives within the `main()` function? The only reason I would ever think to do this is to execute different code depending on which OS is being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object-like macros (`#define` macros with no arguments) are simply replacements. So anything that might otherwise be in your code can be the replacement, for example a literal string: `#define PROGRAM_NAME "MyProgram"`, or multi-line code blocks. Here's a useless example of the latter:

```
#define INFINITE_PRINTF while (1) \
                        { \
                            printf("looping..."); \
                        }
```

As for the second question, it is common practice to use preprocessor directives throughout C code to do just what you've mentioned: conditionally including/excluding code, in `main` and elsewhere. Occasionally I'll use `#define` for constants near where they'll be used, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not only #define strings, people #define code. Although the creator of C++ frowns on use of the preprocessor.

I think main() is too high up for OS specific code. I would try and make functions/classes that wrap any OS specific code. The lower you can place  OS specific code, the better.

Comment: To your second point: I agree. However, the problem with not including the directives right inside the `main()` function is that you might have to declare global variables.

Comment: @Redmastif I would do everything possible to make your global variables classes which contain the #defines.